# Extract hyperlink from website using VBA facing error

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, hyperlink

I am trying to extract all the hyperlinks which contains"http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/" from the webpages I input.

Firstly, the code ran well but after then I am facing the problems which I could not extract the url link that I needed. It just missing every time i run the sub.[image]

Link:http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=SH&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All

```
Sub scrapeHyperlinks()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim ElementCol As Object
    Dim Link As Object
    Dim erow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer


    For u = 1 To 50
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate Cells(u, 2).Value
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to websitehahaha"
    DoEvents

    Loop
    Set html = IE.document
    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each Link In ElementCol
    erow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Cells(erow, 1).Value = Link
    Cells(erow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
    Next
    Next u

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$152184").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/???????", Operator:=xlAnd

    For k = 1 To [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
    If Rows(k).Hidden = True Then
    Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
    k = k - 1
    End If
    Next k


    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to get the qualifying `hrefs` that you mention from the URL given I would use the following. It uses a CSS selector combination to target the URLs of interest from the specified page.

The CSS selector combination is

```
#bm_ajax_container [href^='/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/']
```

This is a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) looking for elements with attribute `href` whose value starts with `/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/`, and having a parent element with id of `bm_ajax_container`. That parent element is the ajax container div. The [`"#"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) is an id selector and the "[[]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) " indicates an attribute selector. The `"^"` means starts with.

**Example of container div and first matching href:**

[image]

As more than one element is to be matched the CSS selector combination is applied via `querySelectorAll` method. This returns a `nodeList` whose `.Length` can be traversed to access individual items by index.

The full set of qualifying links are written out to the worksheet.

---

**Example CSS query results from page using selector (sample):**

[image]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/#/?category=SH&sub_category=all&alphabetical=All"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim links As Object, i As Long
        Set links = .document.querySelectorAll("#bm_ajax_container [href^='/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/']")
        For i = 0 To links.Length - 1
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Cells(i + 1, 1) = links.item(i)
            End With
        Next i
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank QHarr,it works very well,you have been simplified the whole process.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Comment: hi, may I know how did you get the Example CSS query results from page using selector in the sample?